# Makefile is looking MQ library in wrong place on LINUX

Tags: c, msmq

In my makefile I have a line

```
/usr/bin/gcc -m64 -DMQ_SEND  /home/avalanche/oleg/src/ctm_mq_con_ex.o -o  /home/avalanche/oleg/bin/ctm_mq_con_ex -LP/opt/mqm/lib64 -lmqm -lmqmcs -lmqmzse -lnsl -ldl
```

When I run it, the error is:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lmqm
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lmqmcs
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lmqmzse
```

What I don't understand, is why it is trying to find MQ library in wrong place:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lmqm
```

If I know MQ library is:

```
/opt/mqm/lib/libmqm.so    
/opt/mqm/lib/libmqm_r.so    
/opt/mqm/lib/libmqmcs.so    
/opt/mqm/lib/compat/libmqm.so    
/opt/mqm/lib/compat/libmqm_r.so    
/opt/mqm/lib/libmqmcs_r.so/    
opt/mqm/lib/libmqmzse.so/    
opt/mqm/lib64/libmqm.so/    
opt/mqm/lib64/libmqm_r.so/    
opt/mqm/lib64/libmqmcs.so/    
opt/mqm/lib64/compat/libmqm.so/    
opt/mqm/lib64/compat/libmqm_r.so/    
opt/mqm/lib64/libmqmcs_r.so/    
opt/mqm/lib64/libmqmzse.so
```

Answer (score 0):

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-l

-l option is for static object libraries which is libsomething.a files.
As I see your /opt/mqm is likely have nothing of this kind. Only .so shared object libs there. 
Probably you configured MQ make stuff with wrong option to not generate static libs?